# Test if input values match constant value

Tags: javascript, string, testing, variable-assignment

Ive got an assignment and am a bit stuck.

Need to match an input string to the values in a constant, but I am matching individual characters.

My constant would be `ALPHABET = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ'`

My input would be, `var input = 'ABOZ'`

I need a test to check if each letter in the input variable exist in the ALPHABET constant.

Hope I made sense.

Cheers

Comment: I did a .search on the input string but I can only match if the letters are in order in the constant, I can't match in any order, just throws up a false.

Comment: Post your code so we can have a look

Comment: @MarkWalters This is just some test code...                                           ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
inputTest = "ABBC"
var n=ALPHABET.search(inputTest);

alert(n);

Answer (score 3):

Here's a single line answer to your question:

`(ALPHABET.match(new RegExp((input.split('').join('|')), 'g'))).length == input.length`

which would return `true` only if all the characters in `input` are present in `ALPHABET`

Here's a working demo http://jsfiddle.net/kayen/akL4A/

Answer (score 0):

One way is to loop over the input and search if it exits in the constant

Possible code

```
var ALPHABET = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ';
var input = 'ABOZ'
var count = 0;  
    for(x in input) {
        if(ALPHABET.indexOf(input[x])>-1){
            count++;
            continue;
        }
        else{
            break;
        }

    }
if(count==input.length) {
    alert("true");       
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hbh7h/)

Answer (score 0):

Tested and works in Firefox 16. Remember this implementation does not verify if input is null or other defensive checks. You should do it by yourself.
This is a case sensitive result.

Case insensitive :

```
    function validInput(input) {
        var ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ";
        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            var charAtI = input.charAt(i);
            var indexOfCharAtI = ALPHABET.indexOf(charAtI);
            if (indexOfCharAtI < 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Case insensitive :

```
    function validInput(input) {
        var ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ";
        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            var charAtI = input.charAt(i);
            charAtI = charAtI.toUpperCase();
            var indexOfCharAtI = ALPHABET.indexOf(charAtI);
            if (indexOfCharAtI < 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a function which would return true for a match or false for a mismatch. (Please note this is a case sensitive test).

```
var ALPHABET = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
var input = 'ABOZ';

function testStr(str, constant){
  var matchFlag = true;
  var strSplit = str.split("");
  for(var i=0; i<strSplit.length;i++){
    if(constant.indexOf(strSplit[i]) == -1){
       matchFlag = false;
    }
  }
  return matchFlag;
} 
alert(testStr(input, ALPHABET)); //TRUE
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7mrxG/)