# Check if input values totally match on a constant value Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, testing

Ok actually this question related on this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892627/test-if-input-values-match-constant-value) but the thing is we are going to match a word from the user input into the contant values.

My constant would be `TAGS = '101 APPLE, 102 BEAR, 103 CAT, 104 DOG'.split(",");`

My input would be `var input = '101 APPLE'`

I need to check if my input variable exist in the `TAGS` constant.

Hope you can help me guys.

Answer (score 1):

You can;

```
var found = $.inArray(input, TAGS) > -1;
```

(You would need to remove the space after the `,` in the literal string or replace them before splitting)

Comment: Oh common its just a one line statement! Men this is great! Thanks by the way

Answer (score 0):

For crossbrowser solution, see [$.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

```
if($.inArray(input,TAGS) > -1) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if(TAGS.indexOf("101 APPLE") > -1){ ... }
or 
if($.inArray("101 APPLE",TAGS) > -1) { ... }
```